# ling sql group with join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linq sql query:

```
var orderitems =
    from orderItem in Order_ProductItems
    //join style in Products_Styles on orderItem.Style equals style.Index
    where orderItem.SalesOrderID == 123
    group orderItem by orderItem.FrameNo into grp
    select new
    {
        FrameNo = grp.Key,
        Count = grp.Select(x => x.FrameNo).Count(),
        TotalCost = grp.Sum(x=>x.CostPrice),
        OverAllWidth = grp.Single(x=>x.HardwareType==3).OverallHeight,
        //Name = style.Name, 
        //ImagePath = style.External_Image_Path
    };
```

I'm trying to get the data from Product_Styles to tag along, but it's not working...

The above works, but not when i uncomment the bits above....

Comment: It's not working? I don't understand why after so many questions you still use this nondescript phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `style` in your group, then reference `orderItem` and `style` in your `select`:

```
var orderitems =
    (from orderItem in Order_ProductItems
     join style in Products_Styles on orderItem.Style equals style.Index
     where orderItem.SalesOrderID == 123
     group new { orderItem, style } by orderItem.FrameNo into grp
     select new
     {
         FrameNo = grp.Key,
         Count = grp.Select(x => x.orderItem.FrameNo).Count(),
         TotalCost = grp.Sum(x => x.orderItem.CostPrice),
         OverAllWidth = grp.Single(x => x.orderItem.HardwareType == 3).OverallHeight,
         Name = grp.Select(x => x.style.Name).First(),
         ImagePath = grp.Select(x => x.style.External_Image_Path).First()
      };
```

You may have to adjust this to suit your needs, and it may not compile exactly as-is since I don't have an environment set up to test it in, but it should give you a general idea.

Comment: thanks this worked, apart from the overall width part, had to do OverAllWidth = grp.Single(x => x.orderItem.HardwareType == 3).orderItem.OverallWidth, which seems odd to me?

Answer (score 0):

according to @GrantWinney post, you need to select `Name`, and `ImagePath` like this:

```
Name = grp.FirstOrDefault().style.Name,
ImagePath = grp.FirstOrDefault().style.External_Image_Path
```